# I wanna get a value from variable. But when i show value at console, i see "undefined" , why?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

it's component's code from which i want get value

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import "./Catalog.css"
import 'macro-css';
import Busket from "../Busket/Busket"

function Card(props){

    const [complete, setComplete] = React.useState(false)

    const handleComplete = () => {
        setComplete(!complete)
        {complete ? <Busket props={props} complete={complete}/>: <Busket />}
    }
return(
    <div>
        <div className="card">
            <img width="200px" height="250px" src={props.img} />
            <h5>{props.title}</h5>
            <div className="d-flex align-center justify-between">
                <div>
                    <p>Цена:</p>
                    <b>{props.cost}руб</b>
                </div>
                <button className="Catalog__btn" onClick={handleComplete}><img width='10px' height='10px' src={complete ? require("../../../images/complete.png") : require("../../../images/plus.jpg") }/></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}

export default Card;
```

it's component's code in which i want bring a value, but i get 'undefined'

```
import React from "react";
import "./Busket.css"
import styles from "../Main/MainContent.module.css"
import BusketCard from "./BusketCard";
import"../Catalog/Card.js";


function Busket({complete}) {

    return (
        <div className={styles.MainContent}>
            <button onClick={() => {console.log(complete)}}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Busket;
```

Default complete is false, and reload page isn't reason for 'undefined'. When i try transfer another variable: count = 0 , i get "undefined" too. I don't know what i should do , help !

Answer (score 0):

Hey the reason i think you getting undefined is beacause of this line

```
{complete ? <Busket props={props} complete={complete}/>: <Busket />}
```

complete is 'false' by default so it will render the `<Busket/>` with no prop/value so the {complete} in your Busket component becomes 'undefined'
and if u set 'Complete' to true you will get 'True' in the `<Busket/>` becasue you are passing the prop only when the complete/condition is 'true' `<Busket props={props} complete={complete}/>`